# What do parameters to throttleShape mean?

Tags: scala, throttling, zio

zio-streams provides [`throttleShape`](https://github.com/zio/zio/pull/1195) which

```
  /**
   * Delays the chunks of this stream according to the given bandwidth parameters using the token bucket
   * algorithm. Allows for burst in the processing of elements by allowing the token bucket to accumulate
   * tokens up to a `units + burst` threshold. The weight of each chunk is determined by the `costFn`
   * function.
   */
  final def throttleShape(units: Long, duration: Duration, burst: Long = 0)(
    costFn: Chunk[O] => Long
  ): ZStream[R with Clock, E, O]
```

I am struggling to understand how the parameters `unit`, `duration` `burst` and `costFun` are meant to be used. From my reading of [token bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket)

```
throttleShape(1, 1.second)(_ => 1)
```

means processing one element costs one token (`costFun = _ => 1`), and one token (`unit = 1`) is replenished after one second (`duration = 1.second`). However my experiments with various values do not seem to result in any throttling, except for

```
throttleShape(1, 1.second)(_ => 2)
```

which makes it hang. For example, how would one interpret throttling in the following snippets (from the PR) which use infinity duration

```
Stream(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .throttleShape(1, Duration.Infinity)(_ => 0)
  .runCollect

Stream(1, 2, 3, 4)
  .throttleShape(2, Duration.Infinity)(_ => 1)
  .take(2)
  .runCollect
```

Specifically, say I want to process 100 elements per minute maximum, then how should `throttleShape` be specified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your initial stream is a single `Chunk[Int]` and in `throttleShape` as it says in comments - you throttle by chunks, not by elements.

Single chunk is constructed from `Stream(1, 2, 3, 4)` because it corresponds to

```
  /**
   * Creates a pure stream from a variable list of values
   */
  def apply[A](as: A*): ZStream[Any, Nothing, A] = fromIterable(as)
```

In which

```
  /**
   * Creates a stream from an iterable collection of values
   */
  def fromIterable[O](as: => Iterable[O]): ZStream[Any, Nothing, O] =
    fromChunk(Chunk.fromIterable(as))
```

So if you want to throttle by elements you should rescale your chunks to 1 element by `.chunkN(1)`. You should do it before throttling.

So in case of

> say I want to process 100 elements per minute maximum

If you don't need chunk's optimizations (to process items in batches/chunks) you can just scale chunks to 1 and then just `throttleShape(100, 1.minute)(_ => 1)`

```
stream.Stream.fromIterable(1 to 1000)
  .chunkN(1)
  .throttleShape(100, 1.minute)(_ => 1)
  .foreachChunk(chunk => console.putStrLn(s"processed '${chunk.foldLeft("")(_ + _)}'"))
```

Or if you want process in chunks and keep same processing rate - you can write `costFn` as `_.size`:

```
stream.Stream.fromIterable(1 to 1000)
  .chunkN(5)
  .throttleShape(100, 1.minute)(_.size)
  .foreachChunk(chunk => console.putStrLn(s"processed '${chunk.foldLeft("")(_ + _)}'"))
```

Comment: @sokolov-artem I'm trying to reproduce these examples, but it seems something wrong with `bust` parameter in `throttleShape`. Default value of `bust` is `0`, but it busts `100`. Any value that I'm trying to pass as a `bust` is just ignored and `units` value is used as a `bust`. So on start this stream busts `100` of its capacity, and after that `100` per minute.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko `burst` - is the addition to the capacity of the bucket. But the bucket is being populated at rate of `units` per `duration`. You should read more about the token bucket algorithm.

Comment: `chunkN` has been renamed into `rechunk` at some point, so you may use it instead